# Initialize volume in user-specified location

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have been trying to read up on Docker volumes for a while now, but something still seems to be missing.

Take this `Dockerfile`: (taken from docs)

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /myvol
RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
VOLUME /myvol
```

If I build and run this simply as `docker run <img>`, then a new volume is created (its name can be found using `docker inspect <containerid>`). The contents of `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volumeid>` is just a file `greeting` containing `hello world`, as expected.

So far so good. Now, say I wanted, as a user, to place this volume to a custom location. I would run `docker run -v /host/path/:/myvol`. This does **not** work anymore. `/host/path` is created (if it does not exist), but is empty.

So, the question is, how do I put some files in a Volume in Dockerfile, whilst allowing the user to choose where they put this volume? This seems to me to be one of the reasons to use Volume directive in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the question is, how do I put some files in a Volume in
>   Dockerfile, whilst allowing the user to choose where they put this
>   volume?

You don't.  A volume is created at *runtime*, while your Dockerfile is consulted at *build* time.

If you want to be able to pre-populate a volume at an *arbitrary* location when your container runs, allow the user to provide the path to the volume in an environment variable and then have an [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) script that copies the files into the volume when the container starts.

An alternative is to require the use of a specific path, and then taking advantage of the fact that if the user mounts a new, empty volume on that path, Docker will copy the contents of that directory into the volume.  For example, if I have:

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir /data; echo "This is a test" > /data/datafile
VOLUME /data
```

And I build an image `testimage` from that, and then run:

```
docker run -it testimage sh
```

I see that my volume in `/data` contains the file(s) from the underlying filesystem:

```
/ # ls /data
datafile
```

This won't work if I mount a host path on that location, for example if I do:

```
host# mkdir /tmp/empty
host# docker run -it -v /tmp/empty:/data testimage sh
```

Then the resulting path will be empty:

```
/ # ls /data
/ #
```

This is another situation in which an `ENTRYPOINT` script could be used to populate the target directory.

Comment: I understand that a volume is created when an image is run. However, when I do not use the -v option, the volume is populated at runtime by files specified at build time. I was trying to think of reasons behind the VOLUME directive. At this point, the only one I can see is to tell Docker that I want some folders of the image/container stored on the host, but not for persistence (as the files will be stored in a different path with every `docker run`). For debugging then? Seems a very niche use so I must be missing something.